# Are there any Survey Monkey like offerings with APIs for integrating with existing websites?

Tags: survey, web-apis

I'd like to add a survey to a website. I'd like to use a service like survey monkey. However, I'd like to send some kind of REST or SOAP call instead of redirecting my users to their website.

Answer (score 2):

[Survey Monkey has a pretty robust API](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/), but you can also  [embed their survey in your website](https://www.surveymonkey.com/blog/2013/04/23/how-to-embed-your-survey-on-a-website/) with no need to call their API to begin with.

[Survey Gizmo](http://www.surveygizmo.com/) is also a very nice service, with some really great features that Survey Monkey doesn't have. It's generally more expensive though.

Lastly, if you're looking for a FLOSS option, you could check out [Survey Project](http://www.surveyproject.org/) for a DIY approach. It's free (beer & speech), but you'll have to host your own database underneath it and your maintenance cost will be greater. Don't forget that FLOSS is never free as in beer, it's free as in *puppy*.